# Ajax, JSON, jQuery in Silverlight

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, webforms

Can you use Ajax, JSON & jQuery in a Silverlight application?

I have an opportunity with another job where silverlight is predominantly used. They will convert over to something like MVC in about a 1 - 2 years (in C#). However, I have picked up and learned a lot of Ajax, JSON & jQuery and don't want to lose those skills.

Furthermore, there are **no** webforms (of which, I have 8 years experience).

I know I will lose the webform skills (although I never really will, since I have so much experience in it).

70% of the code is in vb.net (I know both, but like c# a lot better).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why not.

AJAX is a means for the browser to retrieve data from a web server asynchronously.

JSON is a language independent way to represent a JavaScript object.

jQuery is a JavaScript framework and runs client-side.

None of the above are specific to any server-side technology, so you should be able to transfer your knowledge easily to working with Silverlight web applications; the only part that's going to change is the server-side implementation.